# How can I append a <span> tag to a <h1> heading in Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

I need to add a `span`tag to an `h1` heading in wordpress. I tried writing in through the CMS but it renders the `span`tag as text.
The site's title is a name and I want to give different styles to the words.
Suggestions?

Following [David Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82548/david-thomas)'s advice I've written this: but it appends the `span` last and empty.

```
<h1>
 <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/">
  <?php             
    $completeName = bloginfo('name');
    $split = explode(" ",$completeName);
    echo $split[0]."<span>".$split[1]."</span>"
  ?>
 </a>
</h1>
```

Comment: I don't know enough about Wordpress to offer a rational solution (though I'd be tempted to experiment with [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)), would you be averse to using JavaScript?

Comment: That would be my last option (JS), `indexOf` or whatever but i'd rather not use a script. Your suggestion was pretty good btw. It, however, doesn't seem to work. Maybe i'm doing something wrong, I'm not actually "fluent" in PHP :)

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `get_bloginfo` as Felipe suggested, but still pass in the 'name' parameter.

I was just working on the same code for the same reason and thought I should post for future visitors:

```
<?php 
      $completeName = get_bloginfo('name');
      $nameParts = explode(" ", $completeName);
      echo '<span>'.$nameParts[0].'</span> '.$nameParts[1];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply the style to the `h1` instead.

By the way, you probably want to edit the theme.

Comment: That's what i'm doing but under the `h1` i get the `bloginfo('name')` function and i can't separate the words. If I style the `h1` (which I'm doing) both words get the same style and it's not what i want.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see this part. I did not test it, but this might help you: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/seo-title-tag/

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
  <? echo get_bloginfo('name', 'raw'); ?>
```

Can't test it for now, but here's the documentation about it:

- [bloginfo()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo)
- ==> it just echoes the result of [get_bloginfo()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo) and there's a second parameter to this function
- ==> [wptexturize()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wptexturize), a function that WON'T be called so beware!